# How to modify items of TableView of an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a new swift programmer.
I'm building the first app with XCode Editor to iOS smartphone. In this app I'm building a TableView with a Custom cell View.

I have created also a details View to insert or modify element of this TableView.

But this is the situation: (TableView)

> [image]

If I try to click on "+" button I have this View:

> [image]

As you can see I have the command "ok and Annulla". This is OK.

Instead, if I try to click on one items of my TableView I have this sitation:

> [image]

As you can see I can't see "Ok and Annulla" button. I can I fix this problem?

This is the code that I use to open DetailsView:

```
var luci = listaLuci[indexPath.row]
var detailViewController : AggiungiLuceViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AggiungiLuce") as! AggiungiLuceViewController

detailViewController.nuovaLuce=luci

self.presentViewController(detailViewController,animated:true, completion:nil)
```

And this is the code of my detailViewCotnroller class

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.textLuce.text = nuovaLuce?.nomeLuce
}
```

> EDIT
>   This is the code of the method:

```
@IBAction func tornaAllaLista(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        var vistaDettaglio: AggiungiLuceViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! AggiungiLuceViewController
        if(vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce != nil){
            self.listaLuci.append(vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce!)
            self.tabella.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This is the print :

[image]

Comment: Use a (relationship) segue in Interface Builder rather than `instantiateViewController...` This pushes the view on the navigation controller stack automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your presenting a ViewController that isn't in its own Navigation stack. 
Change this line

```
self.presentViewController(detailViewController,animated:true, completion:nil)
```

to this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController(), animated: true)
```

This will push the detailViewController onto the navigation controller stack that your tableview currently sits in

Comment: i'm try to use your code, but instead of detailViewController() I have used, var detailViewController .

Now if I try to click on one items of my tableView, I can see the DetailView. If I try to click on "Annulla command", I can see the TableView Controller, but if I try to click on OK command, I have this error:

fatal error: unexpecetedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @Devester101, I have just edit my original questions